# Extract embedded file from PDF with python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

[*CSV inside PDF*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5nhn.png)

See picture.

> Been trying to extract an embedded csv file from the PDF doc using pyPDF2 but I just dont understand PDF and cant seem to get a useful error response.

Tried using the stream method, outline method, cached... nothing

How do I extract the CSV file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#This module contains all the functions for working with PDF documents.
import PyPDF2 as pf  

# Step 1 Read pdf into a variable
pdf = pf.PdfFileReader('*your file location*')  

# Step 2 "The process of traversing the PDF tree structure"

catalog = pdf.trailer['/Root']  
fDetail = catalog['/Names']['/EmbeddedFiles']['/Names']  
soup = fDetail[1].getObject()  

# Step 3 Stream data to a variable for further use
file = soup['/EF']['/F'].getData()
```

Further information can be found on these 2 resources
https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/
https://fossies.org/dox/openslides-2.3-portable/classPyPDF2_1_1generic_1_1EncodedStreamObject.html

Comment: This doesn't work. The catalog doesn't have this kind of path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have 50 reputation to comment so I'll just respond here but you can treat this as a comment under ClaudNova's answer.

His code worked for me, apart from the PDF structure. It gave me a key error for the second `[/Names]`. I just changed this:

```
    fDetail = catalog['/Names']['/EmbeddedFiles']['/Names']
```

to this:

```
    fDetail = catalog['/Names']['/EmbeddedFiles']['/Kids'][0].getObject()['/Names']
```

Hope this helps.

Edit, this was used to extract an embedded JSON file from the PDF rather than a CSV. I'm unsure if that changes anything.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31438807)